When are 2d RCFTs group-theoretical?
An RCFT is defined to have finite conformal primaries. Verlinde lines lebeled by these primaries form a fusion category. These topological defects are called category symmetry in modern language.
Recall a fusion category is called group-theoretical if it is Morita equivalent to a pointed fusion category.
Here's an example of group-theoretical fusion categories: Tambara-Yamagami category $TY(G)$. It's a $\mathbb Z_2$ extension of the pointed fusion category $G$. When $G=\mathbb Z_2$ it describes the critical Ising model, which is the simplest unitary RCFT.
Another example is a non group-theoretical fusion category: the Fibonacci fusion category. It describes the Lee-Yang model, which is the simplest non-unitary RCFT.
To see the difference between the above two categories, consider as below. Recall (see e.g. hepth/0607247) a defect $Y$ is a duality defect iff there exists another defect $Y'$ s.t. $Y'\otimes Y$ is a superposition of group-like defects. Now the only non group-like defect in $TY(\mathbb Z_2)$ is $\mathcal N$. Its fusion with itself is $\mathcal N\otimes \mathcal N=1\oplus\eta$, which involves only group defects. The only non group defect in Fibonacci fusion category is $\phi$. However, its fusion with itself is $\phi\otimes \phi=1\oplus \phi$, which involves a non group defect $\phi$.
Another fact is in d>2 QFTs the constriction of category symmetry is limited. We have constructed $TY(G)$ but we can't construct the Fibonacci fusion category. This makes me postulate the present gauging procedure could only yield group-theoretical fusion category.
Now I conclude my question: when are 2d RCFTs group-theoretical? Are all non-unitary RCFT non group-theoretical, just like the Lee-Yang model?
